# How can I get only a partial rectangle from a CALayer?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, calayer

I'm getting a "snapshot" of an UITextView as CGImage, but the problem is that the content of the UITextView is very long ( about ~110k contentSize.height ) and when I render the UITextView layer in to the context the memory usage becomes ~130MB which causes the application to crash when run on a device.

Here is the code. `viewref` is an instance of UITextView.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.viewref.contentSize);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//render the text
CALayer *tLayer = self.viewref.layer;
[tLayer renderInContext:ctx];

//get the "snapshot"
CGImageRef imageRef = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() CGImage];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

So, can I render only a partial of the UITextView layer to the image context ?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like the following: (untested, but you'll get the gist)

```
CGSize contentSize = self.viewref.contentSize;
CGFloat verticalChunkHeight = 1024.0;
CGFloat verticalOffset = 0.0;

while (verticalOffset < contentSize.height)
{
    CGFloat height = fmin(verticalChunkHeight, contentSize.height - verticalOffset);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(contentSize.width, height));
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, -verticalOffset);
    CGContentClipToRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0.0, verticalOffset, contentSize.width, height));

    CALayer *tLayer = self.viewref.layer;
    [tLayer renderInContext:ctx];

    CGImageRef imageRef = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() CGImage];

    // do something with imageRef

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: CGContentClipToRect is not found in any headers... Did you mean CGContextClipToRect?

Comment: Why is it neccessary to translate? Does CGContextClipToRect discard the origin-values on the rect passed?

Comment: Yes, I meant CGContextClipToRect. I can't remember (from 3 years ago!) why I put the translate in -- it may have been part of an attempt to flip the coordinate space, but if so I've forgotten to scale by -1 vertically. I see I've also missed out a `verticalOffset += verticalChunkHeight;` at the end of the while loop. NB the caveat before the code block!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this.  UITextView itself inherits from UIScroller, so you should be able to set the bounds to a particular region and just snapshot that region (just as if it were on screen).

How exactly are you creating the CGImage snapshot?